# ¿Cómo recorrer Json mediante Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente Json

```
{
"errorCode":"0",
"msg":"",
"token":"8a5476a0-b88c-4b45-82fb-f70d5a2350f8",
"data":{
        "Name":"MARICH VERDY JOHNATAN KERRY ",
        "User_Name":"",
         "Token_Sesion":"42b218ec-8a3a-46f0-a0d4-
                                        6cb9937b1f87",
        "Id_Cliente":"0914882303"
}
}
```

uso lo siguiente

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.Name);
                });
```

pero no tengo resultados sastifactorios

Comment: Qué error te sale? Estás utilizando `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poderlo recorrer correctamente debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var json = [
                {
                    errorCode: "0",
                    msg: "",
                    token: "8a5476a0-b88c-4b45-82fb-f70d5a2350f8",
                    data: {
                        Name:"MARICH VERDY JOHNATAN KERRY ",
                        User_Name:"",
                        Token_Sesion:"42b218ec-8a3a-46f0-a0d4-6cb9937b1f87",
                        Id_Cliente:"0914882303"
                    }
                }
            ]
    
            $.each(json, function(index, item) {
                $("#mensaje").html(item.data.Name)
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Answer (score 3):

Para **recorrer** un objeto literal puedes hacerlo mediante la forma clásica usando `for in` o usando [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries), aunque necesitarás [Babel](https://babeljs.io) ya que esta función aún no es soportada por los navegadores.

**Snippet**

En este ejemplo se hacen uso de algunas características de ES6, como son [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) y [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/repeat). Este ejemplo permite iterar en objetos internos también.

```
const it = (obj, tabSize = 0) => {
  for (let k in obj) {
    const v = obj[k];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Object]') {
      console.log(`${k}:`);
      it(v, tabSize + 1);
    } else {
      console.log(`${'\t'.repeat(tabSize)}${k}: ${v}`);
    }
  }
  return;
};
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
const json = {
  "errorCode": "0",
  "msg": "Un mensaje aquí",
  "data": {
    "Name": "MARICH VERDY JOHNATAN KERRY ",
    "User_Name": "",
    "Token_Sesion": "42b218ec-8a3a-46f0-a0d4-6 cb9937b1f87 ",
    "Id_Cliente": "0914882303"
  },
  "token": "8a5476a0-b88c-4b45-82fb-f70d5a2350f8",
};

const it = (obj, tabSize = 0) => {
  for (let k in obj) {
    const v = obj[k];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Object]') {
      console.log(`${k}:`);
      it(v, tabSize + 1);
    } else {
      console.log(`${'\t'.repeat(tabSize)}${k}: ${v}`);
    }
  }
  return;
};

it(json);
```