# Como carga datos desde ajax cuando la pagina se carga?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

Lo que quiero hacer es que al entrar a la pagina se cargue una tabla con la informacion de los usuarios, pero utilizando JS, no me gusta meter codigo PHP en el HTML, la cuestion es que no se como aplicarlo mediante ajax, se enviar datos, que seria: `$.post("Datos.php", datos_a_enviar, exito)`, en la que datos es la pagina PHP, datos_a_enviar_ las variables, y exito la funcion que se ejecuta al tener exito el post.

Lo que no se es como cargar los datos con ajax una vez cargada la pagina, vi que usando window.onload se ejecutara una funcion al carga la pagina, pero lo que quiero saber es como los obtengo mediante ajax para mostrarlos en la vista?, intente `$.post("Tomardatos.php, exito)`, en la que tomar datos es en donde ejecuto el sql y exito la funcion que se ejecuta para mostrarlo, era obvio que no iba a funcionar, pero lo intente por curosear, no se si me entiendan lo que quiero hacer xD, espero puedan contestarme :)

Comment: Que tipo de dato traes de esa función? Es un objeto, un arreglo, un simple parámetro, te pregunto esto para saber si se debe iterar sobre el o no, serviría mucho saber en que forma quieres mostrarlo. Incluye un poco de código para ejemplificar un poco mejor

Comment: un arreglo, simplemente ejecuto una sentencia sql, SELECT *, y lo guardo, luego lo devuelvo por JSON

Comment: Te invito a que revises esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104063/c%C3%B3mo-recorrer-json-mediante-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

un ejemplo con jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // pagina cargada ejecutar ajax o fetch await, etc. ...

    por ej. con jquery...
    $.ajax({
        url: '...prg.php?algo=1',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {enviardatosaphp:1, otro:2}
    }).
    done(function(res) {
        // respuesta de php con json_encode(array)
        console.log(res);
    });

});
```

un ejemplo con javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // pagina cargada ejecutar ajax o fetch await, etc. ...

});
```

Comment: No me sirve ese ejemplo, vi por ahi y usan $.getJSON ("Tomardatos.php", exito), el cual en tomardatos.php esta el codigo para obtener la informacion y volverlo JSON, pero no me los muestra en la funcion exito